# How to Only set the Font Family or the Font Size in a ActiveMdiChild in C#

Tags: c#, fonts

So I'm trying to use to a menu strip to only change the font family or the font size. But as you can see, I have to put 12 in the font size to make it work. How can I change the font family or the font size by itself while keeping the current font size or font-family

```
private void arialToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
     {
          ActiveMdiChild.Controls["richTextBox1"].Font = new Font("Arial", 12);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) you cannot directly set the Font.Size property so your best bet is probably this approach:

```
var currentFont = ActiveMdiChild.Controls["richTextBox1"].Font;
currentFont = new Font(currentFont.FontFamily, 12);
```

Comment: This works for the Font size but not the font family it defaults to 12 but thanks it was enough for me. Took me hours thanks!